# AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'Message' Python Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Пишу бота для телеграмм, который пересылает сообщения из групп ко мне в группу через канал(который не должен быть известным), Библиотека Pyrogram. пишет ошибка как только в какой-либо группе отправляют message, он шлет мне ошибку.

```
File "D:\pythonProject1\main.py", line 59, in add_post_to_db 'message_id': message.Message.message_id, # внутренний id сообщения AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'Message' 'Message' object has no attribute 'Message'
```

```
from pyrogram import Client, Filters  # телеграм клиент

import shelve  # файловая база данных
db = shelve.open('data.db', writeback=True)

# Создать можно на my.telegram.org
API_ID = 183162
API_HASH = 'd89672a589c14e14129a713a01c86d0c'

PRIVATE_PUBLIC = 'zo7g02h'  # скрытый паблик для управления ботом
PUBLIC_PUBLIC = 'my_super_cool_memes_public'  # паблик куда будем репостить
SOURCE_PUBLICS = [
    # список пабликов-доноров, откуда бот будет пересылать посты
    'mudak',
    'dvachannel',
    'bestmemes',
    'ru4chan',
]
PHONE_NUMBER = '+...............'  # номер зарегистрованный в телеге


# создаем клиент телеграм
app = Client("cyberpunk", api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH,
             phone_number=PHONE_NUMBER)

# обработчик нового сообщения
# вызывается при появлении нового поста в одном из пабликов-доноров
@app.on_message(Filters.chat(SOURCE_PUBLICS))
def new_channel_post(client, message):
    # сохраняем пост в базу (функцию add_post_to_db определим потом)
    post_id = add_post_to_db(message)

    # пересылаем пост в скрытый паблик
    message.forward(PRIVATE_PUBLIC)

    # в скрытый паблик отправляем присвоенный id поста
    client.send_message(PRIVATE_PUBLIC, post_id)
    # потом для пересылки в публичный паблик админ должен отправить боту этот id

# функция сохранения поста в бд
# генерирует уникальный id для поста и возвратит этот id
def add_post_to_db(message):
    try:
        # генерируем уникальный id для поста, равен максимальному в базе + 1
        new_id = max(int(k) for k in db.keys()
                     if k.isdigit()) + 1
    except:
        # если постов еще нет в базе вылетит ошибка и мы попадем сюда
        # тогда id ставим = 1
        new_id = 1

    # запись в базу необходимой информации про пост
    # Обратите внимание, shelve поддеживает только строковые ключи
    db[str(new_id)] = {
        'username': message.chat.username,  # паблик-донор
        'message_id': message.message_id,  # внутренний id сообщения
    }
    return new_id

# обработчик нового сообщения из скрытого паблика
# если админ пишет в паблик `132+` это значит переслать пост с id = 132 в публичный паблик
@app.on_message(Filters.chat(PRIVATE_PUBLIC)
                & Filters.regex(r'\d+\+') # фильтр текста сообщения `{число}+`
                )
def post_request(client, message):
    # получаем id поста из сообщения (обрезаем "+" в конце)
    post_id = str(message.text).strip('+')
    # получаем из базы пост по этому id
    post = db.get(post_id)
    if post is None:
        # если нет в базе пишем в скрытый паблик ошибку
        client.send_message(PRIVATE_PUBLIC,
                            '`ERROR NO POST ID IN DB`')
        # и выходим
        return
    
    try:
        # по данным из базы, получаем pyrogram обьект сообщения
        msg = client.get_messages(post['username'], post['message_id'])
        # пересылаем его в паблик
        # as_copy=True значит, что мы не будем отображать паблик донор, будто это наш пост XD
        msg.forward(PUBLIC_PUBLIC, as_copy=True)
        # отправляем сообщение в скрытый паблик о успехе
        client.send_message(PRIVATE_PUBLIC, f'`SUCCESS REPOST!`')
    except Exception as e:
        # если произойдет какая-то ошибка в 3 строчках выше - сообщим админу
        client.send_message(PRIVATE_PUBLIC, f'`ERROR {e}`')
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Atempt to run telegrabber')
    app.run()  # эта строка запустит все обработчики
```

Comment: File "D:\pythonProject1\main.py", line 59, in add_post_to_db
    'message_id': message.Message.message_id,  # внутренний id сообщения
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'Message'
'Message' object has no attribute 'Message'

Comment: в чем вопрос? Нужно перевести текст ошибки? Если текст ошибки понятен, то должно быть и понятно, почему она возникает.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо заменить message - chat

```
db[str(new_id)] = {
        'username': message.chat.username,  # паблик-донор
        'message_id': message.chat.id,  # внутренний id сообщения
    }
    return new_id
```